# Broken link to Java EE tutorial source

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, crud

The tutorial at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/gfandmysql-part2-138537.html, which is about GlassFish and MySQL, Part 2: Building a CRUD Web Application With Data Persistence, points to https://techdayscode.dev.java.net/servlets/ProjectDocumentList?folderID=9891 (petcatalog application package) as the source code.

But the link is broken.

Does anyone know where I can find the source code?

Comment: Not really a programming question. Meta-programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://netbeans.org/kb/samples/pet-catalog.html),  it is included in the Java EE bundle of the NetBeans IDE.